Switch network failed by @binance/w3w-web3-connector-v2 connector in binance app
Using the @binance/w3w-web3-connector-v2 connector as the wallet connector for the Dapp in the Binance wallet, switching networks is unstable. Sometimes it takes several calls to the switch method to succeed.
